# Message Queue for inter-thread communication

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I wrote this little piece of code, a while back. The intention behind it was to create a system to send messages between consumer and producer threads. I have no idea for what i wanted to use it. I just found it in an old *snippet* folder of mine. The type of the queue is *FIFO*.

**The usage**
Create a queue with `new MessageQueue<MessageType>()`.

*let's assume we will store an instance of the message queue in an private field inside the classes that will be using it.*
*This field is called `messageQueue`*

1. Use `messageQueue.push(new MessageType([...]))` in a producer thread to add a 
   Message.
2. Take it out of the queue from a consumer thread with `messageQueue.pull()`.
3. Check if there is a message in the queue with `messageQueue.hasMessage()`.

I know that I thought about implementing a `messageQueue.peek()` but I never implementet it.

**The code**

```
/**
 * Holds a queue of messages for inter-thread communication
 * Producer and Consumer should <b>not</b> be the same thread!
 * 
 * @param <T> type of the messages
 */
public class MessageQueue<T> {

private static final int MAX_SIZE = 255;

    private T[] messages;
    private int lastReadIndex;
    private int lastInsertIndex;

    private int adjustIndex(int index) {
        if (index >= MAX_SIZE) {
            return 0;
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor of the {@link MessageQueue}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Java can't create an Array of a generic type...
    public MessageQueue() {
        messages = (T[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE];
    }

    /**
     * Pushes a new entry into the queue.
     * This function will block when the queue is full.
     * 
     * @param msg The entry to push on the stack
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public synchronized void push(T msg) throws InterruptedException {
        int newIndex = adjustIndex(lastInsertIndex + 1);

        // Check if we can push the message
        while (messages[newIndex] != null) {
            wait();
        }

        // Push the message
        messages[newIndex] = msg;
        lastInsertIndex = newIndex;
        notifyAll();
    }

    /**
     * Pulls an entry from the queue.
     * The entry will be returned and removed from the queue.
     * 
     * @return The entry from the queue
     */
    public synchronized T pull() {
        int newIndex = adjustIndex(lastReadIndex + 1);

        T shouldReturn = messages[newIndex];
        messages[newIndex] = null;
        lastReadIndex = newIndex;
        notifyAll();
        return shouldReturn;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is an entry in the queue.
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code>, when there is an entry in the queue
     */
    public synchronized Boolean hasMessage() {
        if (lastInsertIndex > -1) {
            int newIndex = adjustIndex(lastReadIndex + 1);

            if (messages[newIndex] != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be easier to test and understand if you could post some of the code that would call the code under review.

Comment: Right above the code, there is a little part called"The Usage". Isn't that enough? I can expand it, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in-depth, just a few things that threw me off as a developer that would be using your class:

1. If you design a queue, use proper interfaces.
   There are a few interfaces in Java, designed to offer standardized access to a `Queue`

   ```
   public class MessageQueue<T> { // A queue should implement the Queue<E> interface, preferably BlockingQueue<E>
   ```
2. Mention constants in your documentation, together with their reason.
   I have a hard time understanding your limit of 255 messages. As a developer that cannot look at private variables, I would be thrown off with errors once I go over that limit. Document it. Tell others about this limitation!

   ```
   private static final int MAX_SIZE = 255; // Mention this constant in your documentation
   ```
3. Is there a reason to use the `Boolean` object type in favor of the `boolean` primitive? Using `Boolean` involves unnecessary boxing and might, if used excessively and in time-sensitive applications, introduce lower performance.

   ```
   public synchronized boolean hasMessage() { // Use primitives when objects are not necessary
   ```

This isn't meant as an exhaustive list, but only my subjective opinion.

Comment: 1. Yes, I could (and also should) have done that. I ll do it as soon as I have access to my projects again. - 2. As far as I remember, the limit of 255 was far more than enough for my usecase. But i really should have included it into the documentation comments. - 3. No reason for using `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. Just a typo. - All in All: Thanks for your input. :)